# Statically created global class instance with a parameter

Tags: c++

Is it possible to have a statically created instance of a class, but with a parameter? This is what I have on mind:

```
/* main.cpp */
  int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    /* obtain parameters from command line and pass one of them to CLog*/
  }

/* CLog.h */
  class CLog{
    operator <<();
    /* some other stuff */
  };

  extern CLog log;
```

In short, I want this class to be accessible to all the classes in my project, thus `extern`, I want it to be created as non-pointer (to enable output with `log<<"something"`), but I want to pass an argument before creating it. Is that possible? Or is there a workaround, so that I don't have to call it `(*log)<<"something"`?

Comment: Like adding a member function to set parameters, and that is called as soon as possible in the `main` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of `log` is before calling `main` so you can not pass a parameter which needs to prepare after `main`. You can pass parameters in this manner:

```
class CLog{
    void setParameters(...);
     ...
    /* some other stuff */
};

extern CLog log;
```

...

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    log.setParameters(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly because globals are initialized before your `main` starts to run. You can, however, create a workaround with `placement new`:

```
#include <new>

char  CLogBuf[sizeof(CLog)];
CLog* pLog = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pLog = new (CLogBuf) CLog(params);
    return 0;
}
```

Whether it's worth it is your decision. A more straightforward solution would be the one suggested by @M.M.

Following the discussion in comments, here is a version with references instead of pointers, allowing to keep the original interface:

```
#include <new>

char  CLogBuf[sizeof(CLog)];
const CLog& log = *((CLog*)CLogBuf);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    (void) (new (CLogBuf) CLog(params));
    return 0;
}
```

Main advantage of such approach is the reduction of interface to a required minimum: nothing prevents calling initialization method several times by different parties, most likely breaking the program semantics. This approach removes init method at all thus eliminating the problem.

Comment: +1 I like this idea (even though I liked it even better with the original reinterpret_cast -- as it stands you don't need the placement new or the buffer at all, just a regular pointer). Since OP doesn't want a pointer (to avoid having to dereference it), why not just a reference? Unless it would trigger UB (I'm unsure here)?

Comment: @syam The cast was redundant here, that's why I removed it. I'm not sure what you mean by not needing placement new or buffer at all - constructor needs to be invoked and you can't create an uninitialized reference. Yes, the pointer changes the original interface though only syntactically. Reference is an interesting idea. Something like `const CLog& log = *((CLog*)CLogBuf);` although it will require to define a special version of `placement new` that returns reference.

Comment: "*what you mean by not needing placement new or buffer at all*" => as it stands your code boils down to `CLog* pLog = nullptr; /*...later in main:*/ pLog = new CLog(params);`, the buffer and placement new are redundant too. As for my reference idea: `char  CLogBuf[sizeof(CLog)]; CLog& log = *reinterpret_cast<CLog*>(CLogBuf); /*...later in main:*/ new (CLogBuf) CLog(params);`

Comment: Uh, I just noticed that both your current code and the one I proposed may suffer from misalignment which would definitely be UB on some platforms.

Comment: @syam No, no! `Placement new` is definitely not redundant. This is what allows to use static allocation instead of dynamic. And it's the same for references, you use it in your example yourself. Don't see misalignment here. The only possible problem can be that size of `char` doesn't correspond to size of byte.

Comment: Whoops you are right about static allocation of course, my bad. As for the (possible) misalignment issue I believe I am right. See [this FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html) specifically the *DANGER* point. `char` has no alignment restrictions but `CLog` may have, and a misalignment will be a problem on some platforms that *require* aligned memory access (and yes, my example using references is also victim of this problem since it relates to placement new).

Comment: @syam this can be said for every time casting is used.

Comment: BTW, any alignment problem will be the same for a standard object allocated statically (this is what the OP asked for)

Comment: No, static allocation is still subject to alignment (eg. on x86 an int will be aligned on a 4-byte boundary even if statically allocated -- unless of course you mess with its alignment manually). And yes, any time one uses reinterpret_cast (or a legacy C cast that boils down to reinterpret_cast) this issue may pop up.  static_cast and dynamic_cast are not affected however since they don't violate the typesystem like reinterpret_cast does.

Comment: @syam Well, nothing stops you from aligning to `int`, for example: `int  buf[sizeof(CLog)/sizeof(int)];`. Also note that alignment is to primitive types only and if it's important for your custom `struct` to be aligned to something other than 1/4/8-bytes, it has to be done manually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My preference in a situation like this would be to use an accessor throughout the code, which returns the singleton by reference for callsite convenience.  The implementation of the accessor could simply dereference an existing global, or it could create it lazily with given parameters, like so:

```
// In public header:
extern CLog & Log();

// In private cpp:
extern CLog & Log();
{
  static CLog * pLog = nullptr;
  if( !pLog )
    pLog = new pLog(/* params, which could be fetched from command line outside of main */);
 return *pLog;
}

// In client code:
Log().DoSomething();
```

If you didn't like the parens, and really wanted the look and feel of an object reference, you could create a wrapper object and access the lazily created CLog via operator->, much as a smart pointer would.

Comment: It's not really clear how do you pass the external parameters to the constructor. Besides that this is exactly what the OP doesn't want to do - dynamic instantiation.